# Git Hub Api. check logged in user

Tags: github-api

I am working on github api--gem  with Rails Framework. for Authentication i am using outh(client_id).
For some reason ,i am not getting who is the logged in github user.
I tried this. http://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-the-authenticated-user, but this gives me nil..

Comment: Could you show a better example of what you're actually doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.. github_api gem doesn't have  this feature. we can have calls with http://github.com/api/v3/user and if people are using github_api gem then pass token as an parameter